# Linq Expression Selector

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression

`Expression<Func<T, object>>` selector is the selector which I have as a parameter.

My method is a generic type and lets say that I want to get multpile property values form the class for which is being called.

`a =>a.customername` is what is being passed to the expression.Please explain, is it possible to have multiple selections ?

like for example I want the customer address also, both are string values.

Comment: you mean `a=> new {a.customerName, a.customarAddress }` ?

Comment: There's a good question in here somewhere, but you should demonstrate it with *code* rather than just a description of the code.

Comment: @Jon, why have <T,Object>, why not a custom type <T,Customer> with matching schema, otherwise it would need explicit typecasting , but in this case we are generating type schema on the fly, will the type casting work well

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: Not sure why you're asking me - I don't know the context of the question any more than you do. But no, casting an instance of an anonymous type to a named type which happens to have the same properties won't work.

Comment: @Jon since you did not pointed out this aspect, which in my view will surely be the next issue in this case, so I first preferred to clarify before notifying the OP

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: I don't think there's any "surely" here. In some contexts, this may be absolutely fine.I would be good if we could know more about the context, but I don't think you should *assume* it will be required. (The result may be consumed via reflection or dynamic typing, for example.)

Comment: @Jon agreed for dynamic types / reflection there will not be an issue, will create issue only for strong type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get multiple properties out, you *could* use multiple parameters, where each extracted a single value, but it would be more common to use a lambda expression which creates an anonymous type. For example:

```
var result = Foo.SomeMethod(customer => new { customer.Name, customer.Address });
```

The compiler will generate a type with `Name` and `Address` properties, and create an expression tree which creates an instance of that type using the properties in the `Customer` object provided.

Comment: @Martin, please use a strongly typed class in the Func instead of object, else you will not be able to effectively use the Type effectively

Comment: If the answer that gave Jon Skeet helped you, you should mark as accepted answer, I think.

Comment: Sorry did not know, done now :)